# Google Play movie rental errors as it says my device is rooted (it is not)

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-3, root-access, google-play-movies

I have a standard Galaxy S3. I have rented and downloaded Movies from Google play before however now it is saying:

> Downloads aren't supported on rooted devices (error 44)

However my S3 is not rooted. All software is update to date. I have cleared the cache but this does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of people seem to be having problems with Google Play Movies. If you have a look on the [play store page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.videos&hl=en) there are a lot of people complaining that the app is buggy.

Lots of people have fixed issues by uninstalling and reinstalling, it may not help but it's worth a try.

Comment: This resolved the issue, although also required a restart.